# Disable margin left and margin right in heading tabs, native base

Tags: react-native

How can i disable that margin in tabs heading native base ?

[tabs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFny5.png)

Here's my code :

```
  <View>
    <Tabs
      tabBarActiveTextColor='#000'
      tabBarBackgroundColor='transparent'
      tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
      renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab style={{ borderWidth:0, paddingLeft:0}} />}
    >
      <Tab
        tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', paddingLeft:0, margin:0 }}
        activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', paddingLeft:0, margin:0 }}
        heading='Home'
        // textStyle={styles.textStyle}
        // activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
      >
        <TextExtraSmall>awda</TextExtraSmall>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  </View>
)
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Apply `margin:0`

```
 tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', paddingLeft:0, margin:0 }}
 activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', paddingLeft:0, margin:0 }}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce and share  a working snippet so that we all can look into it?

Comment: Where are you importing Tabs from?Is it from a library or is it a custom component?

Comment: Tabs coming from native base library